# Yii - checkboxlist with different labels

Tags: php, yii, checkboxlist

I'm creating a checkboxlist in Yii (`$form->checkboxlist($model, 'name', $cbOptions)` - $cbOptions is a key=>value array).

Now I need to change the labels of the checkboxes (translation in a different file than the regular translation).

How do I change the labels?

I tried

`$form->checkboxlist($model, 'name', $cbOptions, array('options'=>array('val1'=>array('label'=>'label1', 'val2'=>...)`

But this doesn't work...

Anyone having an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'name', array('label1'=>'value1','label2'=>'value2', ...)); ?>
```

I tested and it worked for me. You can use `Yii::t()` for "label1" and "label2".

Comment: Awesome, thank you! (Actually, this is kind of a «duh»-moment :)